# Changing the mode when pressing/holding down a buttton

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

And first of all sorry for my bad English.

I am trying to write code that allows the user to change between continuous or manual mode, but I am having some issues getting it to work. The goal is to be able to switch from manual SOS (user pressing the button to SOS) and automatic SOS (the led automatically blinking SOS morse).

Currently, when I press down the button it loops once the automatic SOS and returns back to its normal state with LED on.

How would I make it, for an example switch the mode to manual when holding down button and giving user some sort of indication when changing the mode (etc blinking the led for X amount of time?)

What I am looking to achieve is:

1. Turn LEDS on when pressing the button.
2. Start looping automatic SOS signal
3. Press or hold down the button to change mode.

   - Blink LEDS to indicate the mode change.
4. Switch to manual SOS signal (user pressing the button to signal)
5. Press or hold down the button to change mode.

   - Blink LEDS to indicate the mode change.
6. Switch back to an automatic loop.

The code so far:

```
// set pin numbers:
const int buttonPin = 2; // the number of the pushbutton pin
const int ledPin =  13; // the number of the LED pin
int mode;

// variables will change:
int buttonState = 0; // variable for reading the pushbutton status

void setup() {
  // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // read the state of the pushbutton value:
  mode = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  // Manual SOS mode.
  buttonState = mode;

  // check if the pushbutton is pressed.
  // if it is, the buttonState is HIGH:
  if (buttonState == LOW) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); // turn LED on:
  } else {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); // turn LED off:
  }

  // Automatic SOS mode.
  if (mode == HIGH) {
    // check if the pushbutton is pressed.
    // if it is, starts looping automatic SOS.
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);   // turn the LED on 
      delay(300); // wait for a second
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); // turn the LED 
      delay(300); // wait for a second
    }

    for (i=0; i<3; i++){
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); // turn the LED on
      delay(1200); // wait for a second
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); // turn the LED 
      delay(1200); // wait for a second
    }

    for (i=0; i<3; i++){
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); // turn the LED on 
      delay(300); // wait for a second
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); // turn the LED 
      delay(300); // wait for a second
    }
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    // waits 3 seconds before starting the loop again
    delay(3000); 
  }
}
```

Comment: What you want to achieve is definitely not clear to me: can you please clearly state what would you expect your Arduino to do?  
Eq: "when button is pressed automatic SOS is interrupted and manual SOS signal is emitted once, then no signal is emitted until the button is pressed again".

Comment: Sorry, English is not my primary language but I will try my best: What I want is the program to have 2 different modes: mode 1: automatic SOS signal and mode 2: manual SOS signal (led blinking). And then the option to swap between these two modes by pressing/holding down the button

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'll try to split the code into multiple sections for clarity, but all this goes into one single sketch.

First we define the PINs: defines are pre-processor macros, even better than `const` in terms of performance and space consumption:

```
#define BTN_PIN 2
#define LED_PIN 13
```

Let's initialize the board as per our requirements:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(BTN_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
}
```

Now we define the code which emits and SOS signal in morse code using the standard timing:

1. a long pulse lasts 3 times a short one
2. a space lasts 6 times a short pulse

That boils down to the following definitions considering a standard unit of 300ms:

```
#define UNIT 300
#define SHORT (UNIT)
#define LONG (UNIT*3)
#define PAUSE (UNIT*3)
#define SPACE (UNIT*6)
```

I'm also going to define another macro to emit a generic light pulse, for simplicity I'll use the `delay(...)` function, but this will prevent detecting button presses while signalling:

```
#define PULSE(TYPE) digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);delay(TYPE); digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);delay(UNIT)
```

With the above in place we can define a function to send an SOS which should be both very compact and also readable:

```
void sendSOS() {
  PULSE(SHORT);PULSE(SHORT);PULSE(SHORT);
  PULSE(PAUSE); // inter letter pause
  PULSE(LONG);PULSE(LONG);PULSE(LONG);
  PULSE(PAUSE); // inter letter pause
  PULSE(SHORT);PULSE(SHORT);PULSE(SHORT);
}
```

Now, let's describe what the mode changing should be notified to the user:

```
#define QUICK 100
bool autoMode = true;

void switchMode() {
  autoMode= !autoMode;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
    delay(QUICK);
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
    delay(QUICK);
  }
}
```

Now our main loop will have to check the button and act accordingly, right?

```
#define LONGPRESS 500
unsigned long elapsed;
bool clicked = false;
unsigned long duration;

void loop() {
  if (autoMode) {
    sendSOS();
  }
  elapsed = millis();
  while(clicked || millis() - elapsed <= SPACE) {
    // keep waiting to emit a SPACE or until the button is released

    if (digitalRead(BTN_PIN)) {
      // button has been clicked: trace it and start counting time
      clicked = true;
      duration = millis();
    } else if (clicked) {
      // button has been released: stop tracing and verify click duration
      clicked = false;
      if (millis() - duration <= LONGPRESS) {
        // switch mode on long press
        switchMode();
      } else if (!autoMode) {
        // short press has a meaning only when not in auto mode
        sendSOS();
      }
    }
  }
```

The solution above has great space for improvement:

- there is no de-bouncing on the button
- the board is unresponsive while signalling
- keeping the button pressed forever will prevent any signalling to occur in any mode
- the code is afflicted by `millis()` rollover if you keep the button pressed for long periods (around 49 days)

**UPDATE**: I've added the inter-letter pause as suggested in the comments.

**UPDATE**: apparently `auto` is a reserved word, so I changed it to `autoMode`.

Comment: 1. `#define` is not better than `const` in C++. 2. You forgot the short inter-letter space. 3. Your code is not afflicted by the `millis()` rollover.

Comment: 1. While _better_ is definitely arguable (what's better for me might not be better for you) `#define` does not increase memory usage, `const` requires an additional pointer. 2. you are right 3. it is affected by `millis()` rollover if you keep the button pressed for 49 days...

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at this once I am back at home. It seems complicated but I am sure I can understand it if I just give it enough time.

Comment: 1. No, `const` doesn't cost more memory than `#define`. Try it! 3. You are right, I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Once again your comment on point 1 is correct: I thought `#define` uses FLASH while `const` uses SRAM but I believe my assumption is not always correct... not sure about all the details and how much compiler optimization options have influence on this. Thanks for the corrections!

Comment: So I tried your code, but I can't seem to get it work. It is giving me an error saying: ''expected unqualified-id before '=' token''. Notice that I didn't use the macros as I need to take a better look at those, so I slightly modified the code to use const instead. Anyways here is the current code: http://pastebin.com/mAF6tApf

Comment: I identified an issue in my code and updated it accordingly, but you have other issues in your code as a consequence of your manipulations: missing replacement of some defines and a missing closed curly brace, for what I saw.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too and fixed it again. Now it kinda works but it doesn't have the method for manual SOS from my original code. I added the method to the code but I am not sure how to implement it to your code in order to make it work. Currently, it loops the automatic SOS until I hold down the button for switching the mode, but doesn't change the mode. Here is the updated code: http://pastebin.com/5v6g3igE

Comment: You wrote: “_I thought `#define` uses FLASH while `const` uses SRAM_”. On this architecture, numeric literals and `#define`s tend to be compiled into [immediate arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode#Immediate.2Fliteral). Same for `const` in C++. In plain C, `const` does cost RAM because [it defaults to external linkage](http://stackoverflow.com/q/998425). `#define`s are OK, `static const` is probably also fine.